# Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, log4net.ILog, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using unity-container.I have register my class to IOC container. When i am trying to create instance of Auth class, I am getting following exception:
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, log4net.ILog, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

**Please let me know if i am doing something wrong?**

My code:

```
    using Unity;
    Public Main()
    {
     private readonly IUnityContainer container;
     public override void Instantiate()
     {
       container.RegisterSingleton<IAuthentication, Auth>("Auth");
     }

     public Authenticate()
     {
       var instance = container.Resolve<IAuthentication>("Auth");**//Getting exception here**
     }
    }
```

Auth class:

```
    public class Auth: IAuthentication
    {
      private readonly ILog log;
      private IImpID impIDobj;
      public Auth(ILog log, IImpID impIDobj)
        {
            this.impIDobj= impIDobj;
            this.log = log;
        }

        public Auth()
            : this(LogManager.GetLogger("Auth"), new CAuth())
        {
        }
        public Authenticate()
        {
          impIDobj.Authenticate(data);
         //Some logics
        }
    }
```

Comment: Full exception: Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, log4net.ILog, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?At the time of the exception, the container was: 
Resolving Auth.IAuthentication[],(none)
Resolving Auth.IAuthentication,Auth
Resolving ImpID.Auth,Auth
Resolving parameter 'log' of constructor ImID.Auth(log4net.ILog log, IImpID impIDobj)
Resolving log4net.ILog,(none)

Comment: If you have additional information then edit the question, don't put it into a comment.

Comment: Where did you register your logging component(s) with the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you for feedback. But i am able to solve this issue with "InjectionConstructor". More info is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650802.aspx).

My new Auth class:

```
 public class Auth: IAuthentication
{
  private readonly ILog log;
  private IImpID impIDobj;
  public Auth(ILog log, IImpID impIDobj)
    {
        this.impIDobj= impIDobj;
        this.log = log;
    }

    [InjectionConstructor]
    public Auth()
        : this(LogManager.GetLogger("Auth"), new CAuth())
    {
    }
    public Authenticate()
    {
      impIDobj.Authenticate(data);
     //Some logics
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Container doesnt know what is the type for ILog, and cant create an instance of Auth. 
Please provide the Type for ILog, add this line on your Instantiate method.

> `container.RegisterSingleton<ILog, yourOwnLogType>();`